# how to use this command in c# shutdown -s -f -t 30 -m \\ip address

Tags: c#-4.0

how can i shutdown a remote computer using C# ,i have tried to do it in command prompt it works fine but when i tried to integrate it to my c# code i get  an error targetInvocationException was unhandled

program.cs

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Application.Run(new Form1());

-this is where error is located

form1.cs

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown -s -f -t 60 -m\\192.168.23.18");
```

this the line of code i wanted to use

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried solutions from similar questions on StackOverflow?

1. [Using Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734005/is-it-possible-to-shut-down-a-remote-pc-programatically-through-net-applicati)
2. [Another using Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129395/remote-shutdown-pc-using-c-sharp-windows-form)
3. [Using WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921905/wmi-to-reboot-remote-machine)