# Error: Property access must assign to the property or use its value

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Shell("Shutdown /s /t 60 /c See_You_Again!!!")
    If ComboBox1.Text = "IKWAS-JATI1" Then
        Button1("See_You_Again")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve

Comment: for my project .. to shutdown another pc use vb at computer lab .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to set the button Text based on `ComboBox1.Text` if so you have to use `Button1.Text`, Hence your snippet will be:

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "IKWAS-JATI1" Then
    Button1.Text = "See_You_Again"
End If
```

Comment: Is that you ware looking for?

Comment: before this yes but .. i have problem when i choose pcw and i want shutdown it .. it doesn't work .. it automatically shutdown my pc ..

Comment: whats wrong with my coding ? did i have add "Shutdown /r -m \\IKWAS-JATI1 /t 60 /c See_You_Again!!!"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734005/is-it-possible-to-shut-down-a-remote-pc-programatically-through-net-applicati May help you

Comment: @NurDyiana : If you're trying to shutdown another computer you must of course include it's name or address when you start the `shutdown` process. Besides, what's wrong with un-lucky's solution, and what is Shell35?